# Async function not allowed in forEach with Typeorm query

Tags: foreach, nestjs, typeorm, async.js

I'm trying to do a Typeorm query depending on an element of an object but I have an issue with the `forEach` and the async function.

I have read a lot of similar issues but no one worked for me as expected.

Here is my code snippet with the await not allowed in a `forEach`:

```
public async runBudgetLimit(): Promise<void> {
        const contracts: ContractEntity[] = await this.contractService.getAllProjects();

        contracts.forEach((contract) => {
            const project: UserEntity = await this.userService.findOne(contract.milestoneId);
            const date: string = Time.moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
            const budgetUsed = this.trackService.getBillingByProject(project.contractId, date, '1000', '1000', true);
        });
    }
```

Here is the async Typeorm query:

```
async findOne(id: string): Promise<UserEntity | undefined> {
        return this.userRepository.findOne(id);
}
```

I don't know what is the best solution to solve this issue, I don't think that the for loop is a good solution but I'm open to all solutions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just use `for-of` loop like this:

```
for (const contract of contracts) {
            const project: UserEntity = await this.userService.findOne(contract.milestoneId);
            const date: string = Time.moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
            const budgetUsed = this.trackService.getBillingByProject(project.contractId, date, '1000', '1000', true);
        }
```

Or with slight optimisations - [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37576787/6834220) for differences between `for-of` and `Promise.all` approaches:

```
await Promise.all(contracts.map(async contract => {
            const project: UserEntity = await this.userService.findOne(contract.milestoneId);
            const date: string = Time.moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
            const budgetUsed = this.trackService.getBillingByProject(project.contractId, date, '1000', '1000', true);
        }));
```

Keep in mind that these solutions are not optimal in some cases, because by getting UserEntity for every contract  there is an additional query to the database AKA `N+1 query problem`. To fix this you can load all of the users along with the contracts by using the [relations](https://typeorm.io/#/find-options/basic-options) array.

I am not sure why are you getting `contractId` from the project, isn't it available on the `contract` object?

Also if the response from `getBillingByProject` is a promise you should put `await` in front

Comment: I used the `Promise.all` solution, it's working well thank you ! About the database, the query is a `findOne` on a primary key so there is no way to do a query problem. I'm getting the `contractId` from the project object because it's not in the contract object. There is an `await` before `getBillingByProject` now that the function is `async`.